# swift 3, Which component do I use?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, menu, uicollectionview

I would like to know which component I use to create a menu similar to image.  Can someone help me?

[image]

Using `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Nyktox is correct, but just in case you dont know how to do it:

Insert a TableViewCell in your TableView and then place the tree buttons inside the cell, set the constraints with the custom sizes you want them to be, set the image for the buttons.